# Ethereum Hashrate on GTX 610?

Tags: mining, hashrate, nvidia

Anyone know the current hashrate of this [card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088PVBZC)? Looked but could not find anyone posting ethereum hashrate estimates. Found one for 0.5mhs but that seems awfully low.

Comment: looks like it will meld if you try to mine with it.

Comment: I dont know if it will someone in another ethereum stackoverflow post said they could get 10mh

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on http://www.mininghwcomparison.com/list/index.php
But GTX 610 is not even listed. Only GT 610 is listed with a 0.5MH/s hashrate. Nvidia cards are not good at mining, so none use it, that's why you don't find any data.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 980 Ti and I only get 5 MH/s on Win 10.

The GTX 610 is probably going to be way under that.

nVidia cards are terrible for mining compared to AMD cards presumably because of the difference in how they implemented OpenCL.  I doubt they are producing much more ETH than the cost of the power it takes to run them.

Comment: Ross perkins, I also use a 980Ti and was originally using windows 10 and getting 5MH/s asa you but decided to dual boot windows 7 and now getting 17+MH/s

Answer (score 0):

Other Cryptocurrencies/Algorithms may be better suited for low end GPUs, you should try with Ravencoin(KawPow), Zcash(Equihash) or Vertcoin(LyraREv3).